# separate large KML file into smaller files with PHP

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, kml

I have a very large KML file with hundreds of placemarks. 
How do I parse the file and create single files from each placemark using PHP? 
I want to use each placemark one at a time and users cannot download 12MB of KML before viewing one placemark - unless I can parse the file serverside and only serve up the required placemark to my page, but that is still a huge overhead on the server. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be to **parse once the file and insert the features in a database**.From there you can serve the features either by costructing dynamically kml's or by other more preferabble ways such as by sending xml or json to the client.

Comment: yes - completely. I ended up writing a few scripts to do this nicely and make a few hundred files out of the one big one. the next step is to run the script and add them to the db.. funny thing though is that its really simple XML - one would think there would be more info online.